# Updating the version info in phonegap config.xml doesn't seem to work

Tags: xml, cordova, version

Im having trouble creating a new version of my app in phonegap. I changed my versioning attribute in the widget node of the config.xml from "1.0.0" to "1.1.1" even tried "1.1" and "1.0.1". But it seems its beeing ingored:

```
<widget ios-CFBundleIdentifier="***" versionCode="20" android-packageName="****" id="****" version="1.1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
```

When i upload the new code/zip to to the phonegap build website the build is beeing generated and it says last build 1 minute ago. But the version number in the web-interface won't change at all. Still says 1.0.0. Also i cant update the App in AppStore because its the same version. Any Ideas what could be the issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mine is being ignored as well. Following for a possible answer.